# How to get property from Request object Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have POST data:

```
[{"id":1,"amount":0,"debit":10,"credit":0,"invoice":{"AC_code":"10","AC_name":"Qeyri-maddi aktivlər","AC_id":2}},
{"id":2,"amount":0,"debit":0,"credit":10,"invoice":{"AC_code":"18","AC_name":"Sair uzunmüddətli maliyyə aktivləri","AC_id":33}}]
```

I try to iterate incoming array like this:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
   foreach($request as $k => $value) {
     echo $value['amount']; // $value->amount
   }

}
```

But I get error message:

```
{"errors":"Cannot use object of type Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\ParameterBag as array"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
    foreach($request->all() as $key => $value) {
        echo $value->amount;
    }
}
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#retrieving-input